# Example of a holomorphic function on a non simply connected set which has a (global) primitive

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a non simply connected domain and $f\colon G\to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic so that $f\colon G\cup M\to \mathbb{C}$, $\emptyset \neq M \subset\mathbb{C}$ is not holomorphic anymore.

Is there an example of such a function which has a primitive on $G$?

Comment: Did you try some very simple examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $G=\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and define $g(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ and $f(z)=g'(z)=\frac{-1}{z^2}$, so $f$ has a primitive satisfaes the condition of non-extension by the Riemann Theorem.